# WP FullCalendar using custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically i'm using a theme that has an events custom post already built and using WP FullCalendar, but it has a load of custom fields for the start date and end date called **_risen_event_start_date** and **_risen_event_end_date** respectively.

Could someone help me sort the order this sorts by to be this information instead of the post date itself? I have tried amending this area below but it does nothing:

```
$args = array ('scope'=>array(date("Y-m-d", $_REQUEST['start']), date("Y-m-d", $_REQUEST['end'])), 'owner'=>false, 'status'=>1, 'order'=>'ASC', 'orderby'=>'post_date');
```

Is there something i've missed at all? Any help would be great :)

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: This is no longer a problem..